Volume controls with Bluetooth speaker not working or not synchronized (24.04, A2DP Sink)
My Bluetooth 5.0 device has volume and playback control buttons, but they don't work when it's connected to my Ubuntu 24.04 laptop.
Playback mode is "A2DP Sink, codec SBC" or "A2DP Sink, codec SBC-XQ" (no difference).
The system volume control has no effect at all, only "mute" will work there, and I have to use the speaker buttons to change the volume.
I found a similar topic here and tried that solution (adding "--plugin=a2dp" to the ExecStart command in /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.target.wants/bluetooth.service) but this does not make it much better: Now I can change system and speaker volume independently, meaning that when one is set very low, I can not raise the volume with the other control.
I'd expect that the volume buttons of the Bluetooth speakers synchronize with Ubuntu's volume controls when connected, how can I make this happen?
